Minumum distance to circumnavigate outside of selected loop
I have an edge loop selected, and while circumference is useful to figure out the total distance to circumnavigate while staying on the line, I would like to find the minumum distance needed to encircle the selection without ever making a line "inside" the loop. As my description is likely poor and needlessly complex, I have attached an equally poor diagram, with the dashed line being where the desired output's circumference deviates from the loops circumference. Thanks for any advice you may give.

EDIT: another way to put the problem I need encoded is "if a circle is deformed to fit over a given edge loop, what will the resultant circumference of said circle be?"

How about (duplicate for safety) dissolving the vertices you don't want?

I'm just trying to measure this pseudo-circumference minimum, I fail to see where a question on dissolving vertecies detects and flattens concave faces in multiple edges

There is a Convex Hull node in the Geometry Nodes arsenal you can use for that I think
